# A site gives $x^2 - y^2$ for a hyperboloid-lie 3d graph, what about z? Is there a name for this 3d graph?

Tags: 3d

A site https://www.math3d.org/ renders this 3d graph as its homepage

[image]

and gives this formula for that graph

$x^2 - y^2$

What about z? What is the full formula for that graph? Is there a name for this 3d graph?

Comment: I think the equation is $z = x^2 - y^2$.

Comment: That site doesn't work properly on my phone, so I made this [Sage version](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwtjt0KgzAMhe99itzZbtW5joEIhT2J0lWLgv2h7Zx9-7XOXISck8OXbNyhciexxMVr0WFyXIRinCQMSLE77gpIpSgwoBfV00O-9Zg0qhQBhQ9HJr33FCqIZyYjhEQ7gYg7cFP4OA0aNfUTrpB8ljcsYrgl-h_iZ_NFdjXhMSJJ8pWzZW-wJr3nWduQIwzGcrGEyJq6JSDMahxDQp6j4tbXs98wxj8mMT5Z&lang=sage).

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you. That's really handy. I guess `bnd` indicates $x \in (-1, 1)$ and $y \in (-1, 1)$. What does bnd itself stand for? Does it come from something like "belong natural division"?

Comment: No worries. `bnd` is just an abbreviation for "bounds", so yes, with the default $m=1$ the bounds on $x$ & $y$ are what you said. In proper programs I try to use less cryptic names, but I tend to be more terse when I'm writing a program that has to fit inside a comment. ;) You can read about 3D plotting in Sage [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plot3d/sage/plot/plot3d/introduction.html), if you want to play with the script. You can easily change the colour scheme, *most* of the colormap names [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html) work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ z= f(x,y)=x^2-y^2 $$

is a Monge plot you have shown for the hyperbolic paraboloid, aka hypar. It has negative Gauss Curvature;  what is shown at the centre  is one among Saddle Points.